# Salary of the Prize Queen?

Tags: keijo

Does anyone know exactly how much a prize queen is paid? I know it must be a lot since that is Nozomi's goal and all. But is there a precise dollar amount stated?

Or is it implied to be the same tier as like a world champion?

Comment: At the very least, [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%B6%E5%A5%B3!!!!!!!!#.E7.94.A8.E8.AA.9E) mentions that "top (Keijo) players' prize is (so high that it's) incomparable to pro athletes'". Prize Queen's might be out of league.